# Post image on facebook with custom text on it

Tags: php, facebook, image, upload

I'm currently building a quiz application for facebook, which would have a photo uploaded on the user's wall as a result.

I know the way to post static image uploads, but I'd like to have the user's name and result written on it (Like a certificate)

Is it possible to do this without having to store the modified image on the script's server during the posting session? I'm interested in a solution with feeding facebook a php script's link which generates the altered image's data, but does not save it onto the host's server.

Is it possible this way, or it must first be created and then deleted after the posting is complete?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

It looks like the facebook API does not accept an image generating php as a source, so I had to output a JPEG file, upload it to Facebook, and then delete the same JPEG file from server.

Answer (score 0):

What Facebook does is when you post something on a user's feed, they "store" the image on their own server by downloading the image from the URL you provide.

What I think you can do is you can create a script that generates the image, but your server doesn't necessarily have to store it, you can just generate it for Facebook to download.